# Is there a way to access Microsoft Graph API by using an access token obtained from authenticating a user on Keycloak?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, keycloak, access-token

On the Keycloak side of things, I have configured an IDP (makes use of OIDC) that makes use of Azure AD. That is, I have created an app on the Azure AD portal, and set an appropriate redirect uri. I'm able to to retrieve the access token after having authenticated a user. However, I want to be able to access Graph API using the aforesaid token. Is there any way to do so? Or if there are alternatives, could someone direct me in the right way? FYI, I'm using Keycloak version 21.1.1 (My organisation makes use of the same).

Here are some pictures that depict the above scenario:
[Authentication using Microsoft Azure (IDP that I created)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s105H.png)

[Token retrieved after authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0pPR.png)

I did try and follow whatever that was pointed out in this https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/is-it-possible-to-use-an-keycloak-accesstoken-to-get-access-to-the-microsoft-graph/6831, but wasn't able to configure any of the client scopes or map the user to an appropriate role (not sure if it has to do with the updated Keycloak version).
I've set the necessary scopes on azure AD as well (mail.read, mail.write etc.). If someone could help me with this, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The token you have right now is the token for *your* application. Microsoft Graph is a separate app on its own and you would need to request an access token for it as such with scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` (will request the scopes defined in your application).

Depending on which part of your application needs to make the request to Microsoft Graph - frontend (JS) vs backend - you would have to either use the [Auth Code Grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) or [On-Behalf-Of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) Flows.